# outlook add-in not translated

Tags: c#, localization, outlook, ms-office, outlook-2007

I have created an outlook 2007 add-in with localization support (using resources files).
on start up of the add-in i set  the current culture and current ui culture to spanish. if i run from visual studio, my add-in is fine and is translated to spanish.
when i install my add-in and run it from outlook, it stays in english.

any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im impressed of how little are those with experience in outlook add-In.

Anyway, i found the solution: Place your resources dlls in the GAC

Comment: It would be nice if you could share your solution so that others could learn.

Comment: Just place your resources dll's in the GAC